# How to make Postfix and Dovecot reload data from a database automatically?

Tags: linux, email, postfix, dovecot, systemd

I'm running my own email server. Whenever I change data in Postgresql in "domains, aliases, etc", I have to

```
sudo systemctl restart postfix

sudo systemctl restart dovecot
```

**each time** to apply the changes to postfix and dovecot.

Is there an alternative way?

update:

Say, I want postfix and dovecot to suck up the changes automatically once they occur, with no effort on my own.

Comment: When you use a database for lookups, you shouldn't need to reload at all; postfix should get the new data from the database. What does your config look like? How have you tested it?

Comment: If you're adding well-formed data you could write a script that accepts this data, feeds it into the database, and then reloads postfix and/or dovecot. Better for future maintenance or when you're on holiday, too, because it's one less thing for anyone to forget

Comment: `postmap` is the correct command for testing, i.e. `postmap -q address@example.com pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql-virtual.cf`

Comment: My similar setup using mysql just reads the db... each time it needs to do a look up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `systemctl reload postfix dovecot` should be enough to pickup configuration changes.
2. You shouldn't need to issue anything if you're just changing the data in postgres.
   Though my live systems only `ldap_table` and not `pgsql_table`, there shouldn't be a material difference in the lack of reload without configuration change.

Comment: my question isn't whether or not that's enough

Comment: `reload` and `restart` aren't quite the same. My answer is in two independent parts, which hopefully my edit has clarified.